# Homogeneous table of contents changing the font size

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, fontsize, indexing

I was doing my thesis when I noticed that in the table of content one of the lines got a huge letter. How can I make the font appear in the table of contents on this line equal to that of the other chapters? I would like the table of content to be homogeneous.

Index photo:

[image]

Excerpt from the code used:

````
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=4cm,bottom=4.9cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{mathtools,float,geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,array,tabularx,threeparttablex}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{catoptions}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{cite}
%\setcitestyle{square}
\usepackage{afterpage}  % blank pages
\usepackage{multirow}  % table
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}  % table
\usepackage{xpatch}  % table
\usepackage{tabu}  % table
\usepackage{hhline}  % cell color does not overlap cell line
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  % headers
\usepackage{breakcites}  % references do not go though margins
\usepackage{sectsty}  % change chapter title size
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}  % four level contents
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}  % numbered four level contents
\usepackage{amsfonts}  % math
\usepackage{amsmath}  % math
\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{hyperref}  % references
\begin{document}
\hypertarget{2}{}

\chapter{\huge Propriedades, síntese e aplicações de MoSe$_\mathbf{2}$}

\rhead{ Propriedades, síntese e aplicações de MoSe$_\mathbf{2}$}
\lhead{Capítulo 2}

\vspace{-1.6cm}

% Gray Line
\begingroup
\color{gray}
\par\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\endgroup
\hypertarget{2.1}{\section{Ligações químicas, polimorfismo e hiato de energia de MoSe$_\mathbf{2}$}}

abcdefghij.
\end{document}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the optional `\chapter` argument which puts its content into the ToC and page headers.

```
\chapter[Toc and header text]{\huge body title text}
```

In your MWE you changed the normal chapter title size. Unfortunately I had to make some alterations to your MWE like, among others, adding in the `\documentclass...` macro to get it to compile

Answer (score 2):

You have `\huge` *inside* the `\chapter` command. That makes its way into the ToC where you also see the `\huge` formatting. For consistency, use packages that tap into the sectional unit formatting where you can make changes consistently. One such example is [`sectsty`](//ctan.org/pkg/sectsty), which you already include.

So, remove `\huge` from the second `\chapter` command and rather add something like this to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\huge\bfseries}
```